# Partially nested ANOVA

Tags: anova, unbalanced-classes, nested-models

I have a data set that I would describe as unbalanced or partially nested and I am unclear about how to proceed. My data is nested as follows. The number of samples I have is listed in parentheses.

Site 1 - North: Zones A (4), B (4), C (3)

Site 1 - South: Zones A (4), B(4), C(0)

Site 2 - (8)

Site 3 - (8)

Sites 2 and 3 have no zones, but we sampled an area equivalent to two zones. The original thought was that I would combine data from the north and south zones by zone, but there was a significant effect of North vs. South, so now I don't feel comfortable combining them. So really there are three levels of hierarchy for Site 1- Site, side (N/S), and zone, while there is only one level for sites 2 and 3.

I am wondering if there is a way to address this using a nested mixed-effects model? What I have done for now is run a one-way anova using no nesting, so my factors are: Site 1 A, Site 1 B, Site 1 C, Site 2 A, Site 2 B, Site 2 C, Site 3, Site 4. But I know that it is incorrect.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Yes, within site 1 you can nest North/South effects, and within the North/South effects you can next the zones. Sites 2 and 3 would have no nesting within them.

Comment: Thanks! What type of test allows you do to this though?

Comment: Personally, I am content to study and describe the posterior distribution of the parameters without a test. But I suppose you could setup a [contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)) along with a decision rule in order to have  a test.